# how to make table cell height smaller than text height in word

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2013, table-styles

I have a table in word where I need to have cell's height smaller than the actual font permits it. I tried settting vertical cell padding to negative amounts but word doesn't let me. Can anyone help?

[image: See image preview here]

Answer (score 4):

There are two things that I'd recommend you try -

1. Select the text, go to line spacing options, and set both the **Spacing** ***before*** and ***after*** to 0pt

   [image: Click here for screenshot]
2. Select the row which you want to have the custom height, Go to Table properties, and then specify the height after a little trial and error, but ensure that the drop down is set to "**exactly**" and not "**at least**" as shown here:

   [image: here]

These two steps should get your job done.

Comment: As an observation, while you are doing (1), also set the Line Spacing to "Exactly" and reduce the point size. Then I do not think you actually need (2).